# Switching environment on android Espresso Test

Tags: android, automation, android-espresso

I am trying to automate my android application. When I start the test I try to switch environment from the debug drawer. While switching environment the application closed and opens a new instance for that particular environment. The test fails the time the application closes.

Getting this error: Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''

IS there any way the script does not fail and wait until the new application opens

Answer (score 0):

You need to use uiautomator along with espresso for this kind of use cases.Use Uiautomator to switch the environment and then let the espresso steps run.

For more details refer-https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator

> The UI Automator testing framework provides a set of APIs to build UI tests that perform interactions on user apps and system apps. The UI Automator APIs allows you to perform operations such as opening the Settings menu or the app launcher in a test device. The UI Automator testing framework is well-suited for writing black box-style automated tests, where the test code does not rely on internal implementation details of the target app.